# regular expressions to remove semicolons in string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove semicolons from the end of matches inside a string

so:

```
 var ourstring = " (1); (2);; (3) ; (4) ;; (5) ; ; (6); ;  (7); ;; (8)";
```

become:

```
(1) (2) (3) (4) (5) ; (6) ; (7) ;; (8)
```

The problem is i don't know how to do that. I have tried to use regular expressions: `\s*(?=[;*])[;]+(?!\s)?/g` inside replace, but did not get the wanted results. Please show me how to do that in plain javascript

Comment: Can you explain when you want a semicolon removed and when not?

Comment: @Aron looks like he wants to remove only a `single` semicolon when found between `) (`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.

```js
var ourstring = " (1); (2);; (3) ; (4) ;; (5) ; ; (6); ;  (7); ;; (8)";
var re = /\)\s*;+/g;
var result = ourstring.replace(re, ")");

console.log(result);
```

It removes zero or more spaces followed by one or more *adjacent* semicolons that come directly after a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to understand, thank you very much! and all others who helped - btw i can accept it in 4 min it says